# How to deny access on assets

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a static website, something simple, but everyone have access to my assets, and that don't like me, example: 
www.mysite.com/assets the browser shows me:

Index of /assets

- Parent Directory
- css/
- img/
- js/

How can i render for every access to that url a 403 error page? I tried writing a .htaccess inside assets/ with *"deny from all"*, and "Works fine for me", but that disable my css, img, js, everything on that directory, so this is not a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add this line in your htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: @anubhava sometimes lucky to look when a new question arrives